# getting distinct values from result set in taffyDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, taffydb

I have a TAFFYDB database that consists of 4 fields:
clientID
cTech
arDate
active

What I want is a unique list of "cTech" for a certain clientID inside of a range of dates.

I can match clientID and dates like this:

```
  var ret=clientTechsDB([{
    "clientID":cFrom.toLowerCase(),
    "arDate":{gte:sDfrom},
    "arDate":{lte:sDto},
  }]).get();
```

That returns the array "ret", but ret has many duplicated cTech values.

I tried

```
  var ret=clientTechsDB([{
    "clientID":cFrom.toLowerCase(),
    "arDate":{gte:sDfrom},
    "arDate":{lte:sDto},
  }]).get().distinct("cTech");
```

but that generates and error "*get(...).distinct is not a function*"

I can iterate through and filter out duplicates but I was hoping to do it in a taffyDB query.
How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "get" when using distinct. The correct syntax is:

```
var ret=clientTechsDB([{
    "clientID":cFrom.toLowerCase(),
    "arDate":{gte:sDfrom},
    "arDate":{lte:sDto},
  }]).distinct("cTech");
```